# Js masked data calculation

Tags: javascript, math, maskedinput

It is about simple math question in js.
I have two variable

1. masked value (not integer a string)  = 1.123,20
2. simple integer x.

I am trying to calculate below.
Result =   masked value / x 
To convert from string to integer, I tried to use parseInt.
Unfortunateley I couldn't make it. İt returns with "1" instead of 1.123,20.
I know it is simple one for you all but I stuck. :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: parseFloat, because you do not want integer.

Answer (score 0):

In Java Script, you don't have to specify a datatype, you could simply use 'var' for all datatypes. In your case when you use a string and an integer in an expression, js automatically converts the string into integer  (Except in addition, where integer will be converted to string). So,

```
var a = "10.6";
var x = 2;
alert(a/x);
```

alerts you 5.3. [Check This](https://jsfiddle.net/Lju862dq/).

Keep in mind that,

```
"5" + 1     // returns "51"      because 1 is converted to "1"  (only for addition)
"5" / 1     // returns 5         because "5" is converted to 5
```